# Weird Swift crash stack EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to debug the following crash and am a bit clueless to what this error means. I got it from a user using the app on an iPhone and the crash came through Crashlytics.

The crash was titled: EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe 
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

> Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread 0  Mutual
>   0xfff58 AlbumViewController.(getFacebookAlbums(() -> ()?) ->
>   ()).(closure #1) (AlbumViewController.swift:78) 1  Mutual
>   0xfe95c partial apply for AlbumViewController.(getFacebookAlbums(() ->
>   ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (AlbumViewController.swift) 2  Mutual
>   0xfe95c partial apply for AlbumViewController.(getFacebookAlbums(() ->
>   ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (AlbumViewController.swift) 3  FBSDKCoreKit
>   0x5a2661 -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata
>   invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] + 96

The code that its pointing to (line 78 of the AlbumViewController) is the ending brace of this function:

```
func getFacebookAlbums(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/albums?fields=name,picture,count&limit=16&offset=\(offset)", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let albumData = result["data"] as? NSArray{

            for album in albumData{
                let albumName = album["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let albumId = album["id"] as? String ?? "-1"
                let count = album["count"] as? Int ?? 0
                var coverURL = ""
                if let picture = album["picture"] as? NSDictionary{
                    if let pictureData = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                        coverURL = pictureData["url"] as? String ?? ""
                    }
                }

                let newAlbum = AlbumData(name: albumName, id: albumId, coverURL: coverURL, photosCount: count)
                self.albums.append(newAlbum)
            }

            self.albumView.tableView.reloadData()
            self.albumView.tableView.hidden = false
            self.albumView.loadingView.hideLoadingView()

            completion?()
            self.downloadAlbumThumbnails()
        }
    }
}
```

With an error that is so vague it is very hard to debug. Does anyone have any insight to what causes this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screen of what I have from Crashlytics

[image: Crash Data]

This is the method call and closure contents:

```
    getFacebookAlbums { () -> Void in
        self.albumView.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.albumView.refreshContorl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to add a break point prior to the suspected line, and step over/in in order to find the exact line that cause this error?

Comment: What is being run in your completion block ?

Comment: Is there any output printed before the crash? This may be a fatalError.

Comment: @Christopher The bug is very intermittent, and has never crashed on my device or simulator, so setting a breakpoint hasn't been effective since I can't reproduce the crash, I only have the crash log that I got from an external tester.

Comment: @Laffen The following code is ran within the completion block:         getFacebookAlbums { () -> Void in
            self.albumView.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.albumView.refreshContorl.endRefreshing()
        }

Comment: @jtbandes I've updated my post with more information. I don't have anything being output before the crash. What would a fatalError mean?

Comment: @Unome Have you find your problem?

Comment: @Unome, not sure if this has anything to do with it, but you are calling your tableView.reloadData from a request closure, which could mean you are not  on the main thread. Would performing this closure on the main thread help?

Comment: Thats a good insight. I'm not sure if I was at the time. And that would explain the issue. Unfortunately, or fortunately. My code-base has changed and this closure no longer contains any of the reload, and does have a Dispatch Main queue for the one UI element it is refreshing. Thanks for the clever insight. This is a good answer. You should post it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass weak reference of self. When self is removed from memory, closure can still alive and try to call self and crash occurs.